# Using Node from Windows PowerShell, can I generate binary output to stdout?

Tags: windows, powershell, stdout, io-redirection

Running Node.js from PowerShell on Windows assumes that stdout must be a UTF-16 text stream.   This generates surprising results for tools which send binary Buffer objects to stdout.   Is there a way to work around this?

Command-line example:

```
node -e "process.stdout.write(new Buffer('abc'))" >tmp.dat
```

- Using PowerShell, the resulting file, tmp.dat is now 12 bytes long rather than only 3 bytes long.
- The exact same example launched from CMD.EXE produces the expected 3-byte file.

P.S.  I originally thought this was a node.js question, but its now clear it's a PowerShell issue.

Comment: Even UTF-8 wouldn't help you. Both are text encodings and cannot be used for arbitrary binary data.

Comment: `start node '-e "process.stdout.write(new Buffer(''abc''))"' -RedirectStandardOut tmp.dat -NoNewWindow -Wait`

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAL, your absolutely right, that does it.   Pretty damn ugly though.

Comment: `cmd /c node -e "process.stdout.write(new Buffer('abc'))" '>tmp.dat'` seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer for this seems to be to spawn cmd.exe and do native redirection with it, rather than depend on PowerShell's redirection model.  It is a little odd as it requires putting the redirection in quotes, as follows:

`cmd /c node -e "process.stdout.write(new Buffer('abc'))" '>tmp.dat'`

It really seems too bad that PowerShell doesn't recognize that since "node" is a native command any redirection should be handled using the native redirection mechanisms.